# Adding hinges to steel box tube that is going to be powder coated - advice

Tags: wood, furniture, metal, steel

So, I've designed a frame built of 3mm thick 5 x 5mm steel box tube, which will have inset wooden panels. This will eventually become a unit for an aquarium.

All good in practice but the front wooden panels inset in the frame are going to be doors.

Problem I have is how would I go about adding the hinges for the doors to the frame?

Suggestions I've had so far are:

1 - Weld the hinges to the frame...might be an issue when powder coated

2 - Add the hinge afterwards with self tapping screws...possible chipping of powder coat

Any other recommendations or come across similar scenarios?

Images attached of original design and the almost completed fabricated frame.

[image: Frame]
[image: Frame]
[image: Frame]

Comment: Won't any damage to the coating be concealed by the hinge?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "arts and crafts" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: @Daniel Do this really look like an 'Arts and Crafts' question? I can't tell if you're being sarcastic. As you can see it is a professionally fabricated steel frame so don't see this as 'off topic'.

Comment: You need to take our tour, and specifically look at the "off-topic" list, which includes "hobby projects".

Comment: It's an interesting question regarding a piece of furniture for his home, asked in good faith.  I don't see it as off topic.

Comment: Building a house for fish is on topic. - It depends on the type of hinge...  attach the hinges to the doors then mark where the holes go, then drill and tap. The paint chipping behind where the hinge goes isn't really a problem.

Comment: Self-tapping can snap off while driving them. Drill and tap instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not pre-drill the holes, put the screw in with tape before powdercoat. Then after complete, remove the screw and hopefully it won't crack around the tape. Or, get a removable pin hinge and weld one side to the frame and cover the pin holes. Or, weld a nut inside and cover to powdercoat. Or, use an anchor system, predrill the holes slightly over size. and leave the bottom open so you can relace the hinge, if need be, in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 'weld a nut inside and cover to powdercoat' this sounds like a pretty good option...was thinking how I could somehow add a nut inside the frame but with it being box tube can't get inside...but now you say it makes sense to create the hole and weld the nut in place from the outside. I'd vote up but my reps not high enough yet

Comment: Drill the hole large enough for the nut to fit. Weld it to the "inside" and fill the hex sides. Then grind of course, and your nut will be "inside" flush with the outside of the frame.

Comment: An alternative to welding a nut to the inside of the frame - which could be tricky for the size nuts you're likely working with here - would be to use a rivnut.  But really, I think the easiest would be to drill the holes before powdercoating, then use self tapping sheet metal screws to attach the hinges.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advice...the solution I've decided to go with is pre-dilling the holes and then self tapping screws as it should be pretty straight forward